# Installing Visual Studio Snippets with Wix

Tags: wix, code-snippets, wix3

I created an installer for MVVM Light and part of the installation is about code snippets for Visual Studio 2010, 2010 Express and 2008. Unfortunately, the code snippets are installed into a folder with a LCID (culture code, for instance 1033 for en-US). If the snippets are not in the correct folder/LCID, Visual Studio doesn't load them (yes, utterly stupid I know. But this is what we have...)

When VS is installed in English, all is well. However when a Geman (for instance) version of VS is found, the snippets fail to register in VS.

Is there a way in Wix to detect the LCID and to use that as a property, in other words to install the snippets in the correct folder depending on the LCID? I know about multilanguage installers but it seems like a bazooka to kill a fly. Any other idea?

Thanks,
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

The user's locale is available in the UserLanguageID property. You need a SetDirectory to assign the runtime value to a directory's name.

Comment: This is a really good try, unfortunately this returns the user's OS locale ID, not Visual Studio's. Is there any way to get Studio's LCID? In my case the OS locale is en-GB (2057), while Studio is en-US (1033).
Cheers and Thanks!
Laurent

Comment: Sorry, no idea if VS leaves that in the registry somewhere.